# How to add controls (programmatically) to a Visual Studio designer WinForm

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, controls, designer

In my current job we are not allowed to use databinding. I’m currently using a code generator (ORM) to generate the data layer objects. In the past I usually generated a data source (from the object) and do a drag and drop to automatically add the controls (with the correct databinding to the WinForm).

Is there is a way to do something similar (programmatically) using Visual Studio?

I tried to use the a copy and paste approach (by analyzing the data of the control, in the clipboard, generated by VS), but unfortunately the format used by VS to serialize the control to the clipboard is binary (I was hoping that the format was XML because I can easy modify that). Other approaches I tried was generating the designer code using a code generator. Unfortunately this only works if I want to create a new form but it is, from a practical point, unworkable if you want to add new controls to an existing form.

Answer (score 1):

Controls are just objects.  Any properties you can set in the designer can be set in code as well.  And event handlers are just delegates.  You can build the entire GUI without using the designer at all -- just write the code.  I've done this several times with dynamically-generated GUI elements.

Spend some time reading through the code that the Visual Studio designer generates, and you'll quickly see how to do the same things by hand.